# Expandable Help Text Container On Icon Click

Tags: jquery, containers

I wonder whether someone may be able yo help me please.

Firstly, my apologies as this question doesn't relate to a specific problem I have, but is rather a hope of receiving some guidance please.

I'm trying to create 'help text' content which will appear on some of the pages for a project I'm currently working on. I'd like the help text to appear upon a suitable 'help' icon being clicked.

I had been trying to work through [this](http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/mb-jquery-components/mb-containerplus/) tutorial, but have found it some what troublesome, so I've trying to search for similar tools, sadly, without any luck.

I just wondered whether someone could possibly please point me in the direction of tools which I may be able to use, or perhaps tell me whether this is a technical term for what I'm wanting to achieve, so that I can refine my 'Google' search criteria.

Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use colorbox for stuff like this (not sure if you had a design in mind, but colorbox is a generic modal overlay plugin).
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

If you look at the demos page for it, you can look at the "inline HTML" link, the "ouside HTML (Ajax)" link, or the "Outside Webpage (iframe)" link, and I bet one of those would meet your needs for the help box.

Comment: Hi @andi, thank you very much for taking the time to reply. Another great suggestion, I'll take a look at this. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Technical term might be
 - "tooltip"

Comment: Hi @Stev. Thank you very much for replying to my post. I'll give this a try. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to pop up a new area or simply expand the current one but if I understood you right, may be this will help..??
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#animated

There is another one for less or more toggle effect.. I cant find it right now

Comment: Hi @Bhrugesh Patel, thank you very much for your reply. I'll have a look at the examples. Kind regards